# How to watch a video with a Spring RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, html5-video

I try to read a video from a Spring Restful web Services.
My web services is launched with SpringBoot (tomcat) and my html is loaded on apache http server.

I can watch or download the video, but i cannot jump at custom time in the video.
This trouble exists when the video is accessible from the web services (src="http://localhost:8080/maVideo"), but it doesn't exist when the video is accessible from the apache server (src="media/maVideo").

This is my Java code :

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/videoSimple/{hash}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/media")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> videoSimple(final HttpSession session, @PathVariable final String hash) throws IOException {

    final String fileName = "/4_videoToto.mp4";
    final ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("medias/" + fileName);
    final HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders(fileName, classPathResource);

    final ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(classPathResource.getInputStream()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

This is my html code.

```
<video id="video_telechargeable" width="360" height="250" controls>
        <source src="http://localhost:8080/maVideo" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Do you know this trouble ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with this class :  MultpartFileSender -> https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4